# Buefy "Table" Component Drag&Drop doesn't work - not even on their website

Tags: javascript, vue.js, buefy

Well hello, this is my first Question here, so excuse me if im doing anything wrong :).

I need a table which is capable of drag&drop for an editor im programming. The Buefy Table component looked really promising, when i tried it on their website in their browser. When I copied the code and tried it, I got the PoP-Up message telling me I moved something, but visually and in my data the elements didn't move at all.
Then I went back to the Buefy Docs, but it didn't work there as well. How??
I am looking for a fix, or for a workaround using arr.splice(). I tried, but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

```
//in the component

    dragstart(payload) {
      this.draggingRow = payload.row;
      this.draggingRowIndex = payload.index;
      payload.event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
    },
    dragover(payload) {
      payload.event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
      payload.event.target.closest('tr').classList.add('is-selected');
      payload.event.preventDefault();
    },
    dragleave(payload) {
      payload.event.target.closest('tr').classList.remove('is-selected');
      payload.event.preventDefault();
    },
    drop(payload) {
      payload.event.target.closest('tr').classList.remove('is-selected');
      const droppedOnRowIndex = payload.index;
      const droppedOnRow = payload.row;
      this.$store.commit('Course/changePos', this.draggingRowIndex, this.draggingRow, droppedOnRowIndex, droppedOnRow);
      this.$buefy.toast.open(`${this.draggingRow.meta.title} von Platz ${this.draggingRowIndex + 1} auf Platz ${droppedOnRowIndex + 1} verschoben.`);
    },

//store:

changePos(s, draggingRowIndex, draggingRow, droppedOnRowIndex, droppedOnRow) {
    state.a.units.splice(droppedOnRowIndex, 1, draggingRow);
    state.a.units.splice(draggingRowIndex, 1, droppedOnRow);
  },
```

The Code above made one element undefined and didn't change the other one.

Comment: Generally it's difficult to provide help with simple "didn't work"s. 
Could you provide some details on how to reproduce your problem? What steps are you doing? 
Are there any log messages or exceptions printed?

Comment: @Geir Well, nothing in the console. Like I said, to reproduce, just go to this website: https://buefy.org/documentation/table and scroll down to Drag&Drop, and try it. Its more like a "Is this a Buefy problem?" question...

Comment: @Geir
They offer the Code on CodePen. Can't post the link here..
...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first argument of `splice` should be the `index`.

`state.a.units.splice(droppedOnRow, 1, draggingRow);`

to

`state.a.units.splice(droppedOnRowIndex, 1, draggingRow);`

Comment: Thanks for the Help! Such a small mistake. Corrected and nothing happens. The dragged row get's undefined, and the draggedOnRow stays the same..